# Maven: why are dependencies declared in parent pom not inherited by child pom?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

When I declare a dependency in a parent pom like -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>deps</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>    
               <!-- not relevant for this question -->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.12</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

above i have declared `spring-core` as a dependency for parent pom.
Now in child pom, i am importing the parent pom -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>deps2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
                <artifactId>deps</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
                           <!-- not relevant for this question -->

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now on looking at the dependencies inherited by child pom, there are none. Should NOT the `spring-core` jar be inherited by child project in all cases. As the parent pom directly depends on this jar and is it not passed on/inherited by child projects.

Note: This question is not about dependency management and versions
I understand dependencyManagement, which is to ensure that a set of projects have the same version and scope of a depencency.

Comment: You haven't put <parent> tag in the child pom, so why do you actually think its a child?

Comment: You also didn't import the pom into the actual `<dependencies>` section but `<dependenyManagement>` so the "child" might have knowledge about dependency settings like version and scope but doesn't actually list them as dependencies.

Comment: @MarkBramnik - so there is difference between `parent` and `<dependenyManagement>` through `import` scope. Right on putting it as parent i see the dependency. I was thinking `<dependenyManagement>` through `import` scope is just a work around for single parent limitation but will otherwise behave just as parent.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Thomas - thanks for your suggestion, see my comments above. Hope i am right now

Comment: First `import` scope is not a work around for parent limitations it's idea is to define a lot of dependencies (in dependencyManagement) in the so called BOM and reuse this (see spring boot etc.) https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html You have written that the `dependencyManagement` in your `deps` artifact is not relevant but in contrary it's really relevant in particular this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between placing a parent tag and Bill of materials (importing the pom in the dependency management section)

Using `<parent>` is a "real inheritance" in maven. You define this tag on the child pom and by that you will get all the dependencies defined in the parent pom automatically (also properties and plugins).

The Bill of Materials on the other hand (This is how its called in the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms)) doesn't import any dependencies by itself, however it allows to avoid specifying the versions of the dependencies in the pom of your application, because you define them in this BOM.

So to answer your question, you should really rewrite the child pom as:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>deps2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
       <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
       <artifactId>deps</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
                           <!-- not relevant for this question -->

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was not clear - `There is a difference between placing a parent tag and Bill of materials (importing the pom in the dependency management section`.  I was thinking both are effectively same, but your answer clarifies that they are not.  Are there any other difference to be aware of . Thanks for pointing that BOM approach does not import properties and plugins too.

Comment: Well, I don't think there are difference - these are different tools, usually you use BOM if you work with libraries (spring boot for example has it) but your "slot for parent' is occupied already, for example by other pom of your company that all the modules must inherit

Comment: Use dependencyManagement only in the parent, and in the child modules do not specify a version in any extra dependency. That is the main advantage of dependecyManagement.

Answer (score 2):

Your child pom is a standalone pom because you didn't specified a parent. You define a parent by adding this tag :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>yourpackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>yourartifactid</artifactId>
    <version>version</version>
</parent>
```

In your case, this block should do the trick :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>deps</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

I know that your question was not about depedencies management; but for people that would not know the difference I'll write some words about that.

Note that by importing your pom in `<dependenciesManagement>` you don't have any impact given that it only defines intentions of use but not concrete import. The `<dependencies>` contains the concrete imports and it's only its content that you can use in your application.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. ++1. see my comment on the Q. Hope i am right with my comments. Please correct if wrong.